# I want to display data from a list with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to display data from a list with thymeleaf 
My class user

```
public class user {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id ;
private String name;
...Getter and setter ...
```

My controller

```
private List<user> userList=new ArrayList<user>();
user u1=new user("John");
user u2=new user("Lionel");
userList.add(u1);
userList.add(u2);

@RequestMapping("/listRappel")
public String listRp(Model model){


    model.addAttribute("user",userList);

    return "UserView" ;
}
```

My view thymeleaf

```
<table>
<tr th:each="t:${user}">
<td th:text="${t.name}"></td></tr>
<tabel/>
```

But when I run it I get the error: `"Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "t.name" "`

Comment: The closing tag for you table is wrong `</table>`

Comment: I know but even if I change it nothing is changed

Comment: can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: excuse me but what means stack trace ?

Comment: the full error that is printed to the console

Comment: ok thank's this the error Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:  "t.name" "

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: user:(pos 9)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `ModelMap` argument instead of `Model` in the method `listRp`?

method would be:

```
public String listRp(ModelMap model)
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting the ModelMap type?

Comment: modelmap works better when you are trying to render a list in UI. I do not see anything complex happening in the snippet provided above, so I recommended using modelmap instead and try it out.